# The same barcode is unexpectedly inserting into my database

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a code for inserting the barcode into a database but if the same barcode exists in the database, I don't need this to be inserted same again, so I coded like this but still, the same barcode is inserting in my database. What the error in this code?

I am using mysqli and Bootstrap to show the errors in the page, the page is executed from another page called product.php via ajax and it is showing in another page called showuser.php as it gets updated in a table which should give the output

```
<?php
        include('conn.php');

        if(isset($_POST['add'])){
            $proname=$_POST['product'];
            $bar=$_POST['barcode'];
            $war=$_POST['warranty'];
            $gar=$_POST['guarranty'];
            $amount=$_POST['amount'];
            $id = $_POST['cusid'];
            $date = $_POST['date'];

            $check = "SELECT * FROM warranty_update WHERE battery_serial = '$bar'";
            $rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
    if($data[0] > 1) {

    ?>
        <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>


        <h3 align="center"><i class="   glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i><br>
    <br>
      Sorry Barcode Already Been Inserted !<br><br>

    Please Go Back</h3>
    <?php } else {

         $datesplit     = explode("-",$date);
         $warranty      = $datesplit[0];
         $guarante      = $datesplit[0];


         $day    = $datesplit[1];
         $month  = $datesplit[2];

          $fdate =  strtotime($date);
          $Gm=strtotime("+$gar Months",$fdate);
          $wm=strtotime("+$war Months",$Gm);
            $m1=date("Y-m-d", $Gm) ;
            $m2 =date("Y-m-d", $wm) ;

         $today =  date("Y/m/d");


          $expiry_warranty = $m2;
          $expiry_guarante = $m1;

        //mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cus_reg`(`reg_id`, `name`, `mobile`, `battery_serial`, `model`, `date`, `reg_by`, `warranty_expiry`, `waranty_span`,`guarantee_expiry`, `g_span`) VALUES (NULL,'$name','$mobile','$battery_serial','$vehicle_num','$date','$regby','$expiry_warranty', '$wmonth', '$expiry_guarante', '$gmonth')")==true or die(mysql_error);


            //mysql_query("INSERT INTO `warranty_update`(`wa_id`, `cus_reg_id`, `new_barcode`, `date`) VALUES (NULL,LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$battery_serial','$today')");

    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `warranty_update`(`wa_id`, `reg_id`, `battery_serial`, `model`, `date`, `warranty_expiry`, `waranty_span`, `guarantee_expiry`, `g_span`, `amount`) VALUES (NULL,'$id','$bar','$proname','$today','$expiry_warranty','$war','$expiry_guarante','$gar','$amount')");  
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `replacements`(`r_id`, `reg_id`, `wa_id`, `new_barcode`, `date`) VALUES ('NULL','$id',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$bar','$today')");  
       ?>


       <!--header("refresh:1;url=home.php");-->

         <h3 align="center"><i class="  glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i><br>
    <br>
      Data Successfully Inserted !  


    <?php }


        }
    ?>
```

Comment: **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

Comment: What i dint get u man??

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure, but you should check you array like this for entries:

```
if (count($data) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is defining a unique constraint on barcode via SQL.
Anyway I think that you are valuating the condition in an erroneous mode.
$data is an array, so you should check his size with: sizeof.

so: `if(sizeof($data) > 1) { .... }`

Comment: can please tell me how can I define a unique constraint

Comment: But why it is not working? 
Could you print the value of $data? 
Is the query correct and retrieving some data? 
Please insert into the HTML file <?php echo $data; ?> after the query gets executed to check.

In addiction, you can an unique constraint on your table like this:
**alter table warranty_update add unique(battery_serial) **

If you can, consider reading this page: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Have a good day.

Comment: yup I had given it as unique, it worked but I cant give an error note for the same barcode insertion